# Change the color of the rulers in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I change the color of the Ruler in Sublime, I can't seem to find the code for setting this color:

[image: Change this ruler color]

Comment: https://github.com/icylace/CursorRuler#ruler-colors

Comment: @KeithHall you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before build 3150, one had to use a workaround to set the ruler color - see below. Build 3150 and after support a `rulers` color in the color scheme. (https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1830)

---

The [CursorRuler](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CursorRuler) plugin has a guide for this in it's [Readme](https://github.com/icylace/CursorRuler#ruler-colors).

> #### Ruler Colors
>
> Speaking of ruler visual style, there's apparently no way to set the
>   color of rulers directly.  Rulers get their colors from your color
>   scheme's foreground and background settings.  The background setting
>   overrides the foreground setting.
>
> Despite the current lack of ability to directly set colors for rulers
>   (as of ST2 build 2219 and ST3 build 3030) there's thankfully a
>   workaround for it [described here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/93504-use-separate-colors-for-the-background-gutter-and-folder-tree/#comment_164903).
>
> Basically, you need to change the overall default foreground color
>   and/or background color of your color scheme and then add a rule for
>   the `text` and `source` scopes which is used to override the default
>   colors.  For example, if we had a default foreground color which is
>   meant to be used as the ruler and gutter foreground color:
>
> ```
> <key>foreground</key>
> <string>#00FFFF77</string>
> ```
>
> then we would add
>
> ```
> <dict>
>     <key>name</key>
>     <string>Text and Source Base Colors</string>
>     <key>scope</key>
>     <string>text, source</string>  
>     <key>settings</key>
>     <dict>
>         <key>foreground</key>
>         <string>#E6E1DC</string>
>     </dict>
> </dict>
> ```
>
> in order for us to define our actual default foreground color.

Comment: Keith Hall: foreground color = ruler color. But if I need foreground color ≠ ruler color? Is it possible use separate setting for ruler color in 2017? [**See also**](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1593). Thanks.